# postscript scaling

Tags: dynamic, gnuplot, postscript

Hi this is a bit of a long shot but I'm curious as to whether it can be done. I'm creating a graph with gnuplot and outputting as postscript, is there a way to make the graph dynamic such that as you zoom in the numbers on the axis scale. i.e. zoomed out you see 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Zoomed in to a section sees 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 .
Cheers.

Comment: This is one of the wonderful things [NeWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeWS) could do. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - 
although a postscript file is actually a program in a full-fledged language, it has no information on zoom level when being rendered.

It is possible that some postscript implementations have a way for the postscript program to actually know the raster resolution is rendering too - and if that is true, it would be theoretically possible, but it would be non-trivial. Non-trivial as in: require a lot of coding in postscript itself, including dinamically generating the label's text - usually 
text in postscript files is "hard coded" in place at time of generation of the postscript file itself. It certainly would not just a quick hack prepended to the file

Answer (score 0):

PostScript graphics state has current transformation matrix. Everything is multiplied by this matrix. Executing PostScript command `scale` before drawing the graph effectively changes the current transform matrix elements to scale the output. Do your development tools provide any means to embed raw PostScript code?

Answer (score 0):

PostScript is a programming language where you have if else statements to control the logic. So depending on a current scale you could calculate you can draw other things. It might be possible if you do it yourself but needs logic that you need to come up with (that is called programming ;-))